# Embedded videos in VB.NET form - referenced from URL online and file

Tags: vb.net, video-streaming

I am trying to implement a video player on VB.NET form that would play videos from both online URL (it could be from Youtube or any other URL that points to the video) or file location. I tried to add Windows Media Player and play videos from the file, which works fine, but I can’t play videos let's say from Youtube. I did some research and some of the articles suggested that Shockwave Flash Object control would play videos from online, but that would be two different controls on one form virtually doing the same thing.

I wanted to ask if there is a control to display videos that would handle both references - online URL and file location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the `Windows Media Player` control will only play a video if the given URL actually points to a video file, for example,

`http://www.example.com/files/videos/MyVid.mp4`

`C:\Users\John\Videos\MyVid.mp4`.

You cannot *directly* play videos from YouTube, because Google do *not* display the direct URL of videos from YouTube, so you have to generate a URL to get to the video you want to stream (although I'm not entirely sure if that's legal).

Comment: I doubt that Windows Media Player plays YouTube videos.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, i can't edit it... To do play youtube videos this way would be illegal, you'd have to download the video then play it. So if you don't own the video you're downloading it's illegal...

Comment: @Sam: You can always delete your comments on SO. Staying on the subject, are you saying streaming a video from youtube is illegal?

Comment: I am not downloading video, just streaming it by pointing to it's URL.

Comment: @Neolisk: Thanks. I'm saying that if you wanted to use this method to play youtube videos, you would have to first download the video, then you could watch it. You can't directly stream a youtube video using this embedded windows media player, because, youtube dont actually give the direct URL of the video you're watching, so without the direct URL you can't stream it. Downloading the video is illegal (unless you own it, or obtain the copyright to the video), streaming it, i'm not sure...

Comment: @RasaRin: To use this media player you would first have to download the video from youtube (which is illegal), then you could watch it. If you have the direct URL of the video then you can stream it, but youtube doesn't directly display a videos direct URL, so you can only download the vid then play it.

Answer (score 0):

i have found that using shockwave flash and on the youtube video link, adding a /v just before the /watch, will allow you to stream the video. (you add the link on the movie properties of the flash module) I don't think you can play videos from your directory though, which i have been trying to find for ours how to do)